# How download a FreeBSD package from linux?

Tags: linux, freebsd

I have to download a FreeBSD package from linux but I have some problem.
I have tried to search the package from [here](http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:13:aarch64/) but it gaves me (on Latest/all) a 403 forbidden error. Anyone know why and overall how to overcome that ?

Comment: What specific package and version are you looking for?  I get the same result as you from Windows - it appears that the `Latest/all` directory does not allow its contents to be listed, you probably have to know exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @patbarron it should be comms/lrzsz or comms/kermit They should be useful to transfer files over serial. I have installed fbsd over raspberry that is connected through serial connection and I have to transfer some package to connect it to internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `comms/kermit` package [here](http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:13:aarch64/latest/All/kermit-9.0.304.24.txz), and you can get the `comms/lrzsz` package [here](http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:13:aarch64/latest/All/lrzsz-0.12.20_4.txz).

In general, you can find these packages by downloading the [packagesite.txz](http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:13:aarch64/latest/packagesite.txz) file from the `latest` directory, uncompressing it, and untarring it - the `packagesite.yaml` file within the `tar` archive contains the locations of all the available packages.